# draw points on canvas using coordinates from database

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, database, loops

I'm trying to draw points on my canvas using javascript but first, I need to call my x and y coordinates from the database with php and store them in a multidimensional array before I draw them using js.

Here is my code and my problem is that I get a blank canvas or in other words, no points were being drawn on my canvas

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM sample";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$query)) {
        echo 'var points=[';
        foreach( $result as $row ) {
            echo "{x:${row['x']}, y:${row['y']}},";
        }
        echo "];\n";
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>

for(var p in points) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(p.x , p.y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
 }
```

Comment: have you checked that your generated `var points` is valid JSON? because i think you need to surround your keys and values with `"`.

Comment: Did you forget to wrap your js code in `<script> ... </script>` tags

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have it but i didn't include it in my code shown above

Comment: Take a look a [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) Its a far better method of creating a JSON String than doing it manually

Comment: @wayneOS what do you mean? i'm quite new to javascript and i am not really familiar with JSON. I had my code above only with some researches and a little help from others

Comment: could you provide the generated JSON-string?

Comment: how should i do it if my values came from the database?

Comment: did you debug?  1- make sure your `points` are indeed extracted from the DB 2- the values you get (if any) are valid in the canvas context you have i.e. not outside the view area, ...  3- printed the p inside the for loop to make sure it is set to what you expect. 4- ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an expert in php, but this code works:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM sample";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$query)) {
  // Fetch one and one row
    $array=array();
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    array_push($array,[$row['x'],$row['y']]);
    }
 }
 mysqli_free_result($result);
 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
 <script>
 var canvas=document.getElementById('mon_canvas');
 var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
 var points =<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>;
 alert(points);
 for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(points[i][0] , points[i][1], 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
 }
 </script>  
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: It worked! The only problem was that you placed MYSQL_ASSOC instead of MYSQLI_ASSOC but anyways, thank you